# Webform email handler - dynamic recipient list

Tags: webforms, 9

Our site uses webforms and for a particular form - upon submission - an email is sent to multiple people. Currently, that recipient list is part of 'config' - meaning that to add/delete someone is a config change and since we are using best practice of configuration as code - this means pushing a new release.
I am looking for a way to create the recipient list dynamically - say based on a user attribute - so that a site admin/editor could modify it and not require a code push.

Comment: What research have you done on Webform’s API? There are many hooks such as hook_webform_handler_invoke_alter.

Comment: Besides finding webform.api.php not much - I can't find any documentation that explains what the hooks do or when they are called (some have minimal documentation/examples). I am familiar with hooks etc- so will have to stumble around. Thanks.

Comment: Also custom handlers are possible. I don’t think this is a bad question however it needs to be more specific.

Comment: The question isn't clear, but have you tried to look at https://www.drupal.org/docs/contributed-modules/webform/webform-cookbook? Webform is more altered with handler than hooks

Comment: Perhaps this specific example could answer to your question https://www.drupal.org/docs/contributed-modules/webform/webform-cookbook/how-to-programmatically-alter-destination-email-address

Comment: Thanks @Giuseppe - I hadn't found the cookbook nor did I really understand webform has converted and extended the plugin model. that is precisely what I am looking for.